# .Net: How to simulate and measure a full web request?

Tags: .net, webrequest

I’m trying to measure a request with WebRequest,

But I’m getting significant smaller results then measuring with FireBug.

I guessing it’s because some content like Images and CSS isn’t included.

Is there a way to measure a full web request?

My code:

```
        public string GetPageHtmlTime(string strUrl)
    {
        WebRequest request = null;
        WebResponse response = null;
        HttpWebResponse httpCurrentWeResponse = null;

        try
        {
            //making a request to the file.
            request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
            //set 5 seconds timeout for the request
            request.Timeout = 5 * 1000;

            //Stopwatch
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            //get the server response
            response = request.GetResponse();
            httpCurrentWeResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            sw.Stop();

            //if the http response return any type of failure
            if (httpCurrentWeResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK || response == null)
                return "Error: " + httpCurrentWeResponse.StatusCode;

            response.Close();

            //Return time:
            return "OK time=" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("0,0");

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error: ex=" + ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code is probably only retrieving the page and does not take the next steps of rendering the HTML that it contains and resolving any resources such as images that it includes. My tip would be to investigate using a browser control instead.

Comment: Browser control is only available in Win Forms. Is there a way to simulate by code only so it can be a part of a Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's an option for you, but you can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_members.aspx) control, as it will request all the elements of the page before firing the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only measure how long it takes for the code complete, the code will not wait for all the bytes to arrive at the client which will take significantly longer than the code.

What and where measure depends on where you expect to make optimisations.  If you want to improve the experience at the client when the server is under light load then Firebug (or Fiddler) would be a good place to be measuring.  If you wan't to improve performance on the server when its under heavy load then code profilers would the sort of tool you would be needing.